# Responsive animated <figcaption>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm just about finished developing my first WordPress theme from scratch: http://bit.ly/16baqTI

I'm having problems with the responsive image grid on the homepage. When you reduce the browser viewport, the images are not scaling correctly. This test works perfectly without the JS (http://bit.ly/19JnexJ). It appears that captions.js is causing the problem.

Is there a better way to serve animated captions? I'd prefer to use JS rather than CSS3. I'm looking to debug the website in IE7+.

Sorry if I haven't been specific enough. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another morning of experimenting, it looks like retina.js was causing media query conflicts. I've disabled the plugin and everything is working beautifully!

More on the bug here: https://github.com/imulus/retinajs/issues/8